# GeoServer - Custom field for GetMap in WMS layer

Tags: geoserver, wms, grib

In GeoServer I configured a layer starting from GRIB file. I need in GetMap to get the image by adding a height parameter specified in GetCapabilities, but it doesn't work.

Hi,

Given the specific part of the GetCapabilities response related to the layer taken from GRIB files in GeoServer:

```
<Layer queryable="1" opaque="0">
<Name>elman:mercatorOceanCurrent</Name>
<Title>mercatorOceanCurrent</Title>
<Abstract/>
<KeywordList>
<Keyword>mercatorOceanCurrent</Keyword>
<Keyword>WCS</Keyword>
<Keyword>GRIB</Keyword>
</KeywordList>
<CRS>EPSG:4326</CRS>
<CRS>CRS:84</CRS>
<EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
<westBoundLongitude>-9.04166666790843</westBoundLongitude>
<eastBoundLongitude>0.0416669361293316</eastBoundLongitude>
<southBoundLatitude>42.958337148030594</southBoundLatitude>
<northBoundLatitude>50.04167048136393</northBoundLatitude>
</EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
<BoundingBox CRS="CRS:84" minx="-9.04166666790843" miny="42.958337148030594" maxx="0.0416669361293316" maxy="50.04167048136393"/>
<BoundingBox CRS="EPSG:4326" minx="42.958337148030594" miny="-9.04166666790843" maxx="50.04167048136393" maxy="0.0416669361293316"/>
<Dimension name="time" default="2023-02-09T12:00:00Z" units="ISO8601">2023-02-09T12:00:00.000Z,2023-02-10T12:00:00.000Z</Dimension>
<Dimension name="DEPTH_BELOW_SURFACE1" default="49.0" units="m" unitSymbol="m">49.0,508.0,957.0,1581.0,2160.0</Dimension>
<Style>
<Name>elman:OceanCurrentHeatMap</Name>
<Title>OceanCurrentHeatMap</Title>
<Abstract>Style OceanCurrentHeatMap</Abstract>
<LegendURL width="22" height="181">
<Format>image/png</Format>
<OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://192.168.8.112:8090/geoserver/ows?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetLegendGraphic&format=image%2Fpng&width=20&height=20&layer=elman%3AmercatorOceanCurrent"/>
</LegendURL>
</Style>
</Layer>
```

When I call GetMap with the 'time' parameter, everything works as expected.
However, when I add the 'DEPTH_BELOW_SURFACE1' parameter as expressed in the capabilities, the returned image remains the same even when I vary this parameter.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you not set that as your elevation parameter?